# Why the image on the splash screen is still cutted?

Tags: android

Hello everyone i decide to make a splash screen that display this vector that i've made in the xml [xml that i've made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IN4xP.png)but the result when i run the app is like this:
[the result when i run the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwQcL.png)

i also tried to make the inset xml file but it still not work.
here's my code:

splash xml (the inset)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_splash"
    android:insetLeft="50dp"
    android:insetRight="50dp"
    android:insetTop="50dp"
    android:insetBottom="50dp"/>
```

and this is the splash screen that i want to dislpay

ic_splash.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="135dp"
    android:height="129dp"
    android:viewportWidth="135"
    android:viewportHeight="129">

  <path
      android:fillColor="#C1B5B5"
      android:pathData="M41.6541 68.2709C39.7582 65.8209 38.3333 62.55 38.3333 58.3333C38.3333 41.6667 63.3333 43.75 67.4999 31.25C71.6666 43.75 96.6666 41.6667 96.6666 58.3333C96.6666 62.55 95.2374 65.8167 93.3458 68.2709C93.1041 68.5792 92.7293 68.75 92.3377 68.75H42.6708C42.275 68.75 41.8957 68.5792 41.6541 68.2709ZM90.4166 75H44.5833C40.4166 75 38.3333 77.0833 38.3333 81.25V85.4167C38.3333 86.5667 39.2666 87.5 40.4166 87.5H94.5832C95.7332 87.5 96.6666 86.5667 96.6666 85.4167V81.25C96.6666 77.0833 94.5832 75 90.4166 75ZM66.3581 29.0751C70.8581 29.7168 74.7997 26.8667 75.8205 22.8709C75.8914 22.5876 75.571 22.3665 75.3251 22.5332C74.1251 23.354 72.6167 23.7671 70.9876 23.5504C68.4084 23.2046 66.3374 21.287 65.8499 18.7703C65.4166 16.4995 66.2708 14.3919 67.8249 13.0544C68.0458 12.8627 67.9209 12.5 67.625 12.5C67.6209 12.5 67.6206 12.5 67.6164 12.5C64.5164 12.5 61.8083 14.1414 60.3374 16.5914C59.4291 18.0997 58.9917 19.9163 59.2251 21.8455C59.6709 25.5413 62.6206 28.5418 66.3581 29.0751Z" />
  <path
      android:fillColor="#C1B5B5"
      android:pathData="M4.18 124.58L0.82 124.28L1.56 110.54C1.21333 110.62 0.893333 110.713 0.6 110.82L0 107.42C0.706667 107.273 1.58 107.12 2.62 106.96C3.66 106.8 4.73333 106.72 5.84 106.72C6.69333 106.72 7.56 106.813 8.44 107C9.32 107.173 10.16 107.467 10.96 107.88C11.7733 108.28 12.4933 108.82 13.12 109.5C13.76 110.18 14.26 111.013 14.62 112C14.9933 112.987 15.18 114.153 15.18 115.5C15.18 117.393 14.8733 119.013 14.26 120.36C13.66 121.693 12.78 122.713 11.62 123.42C10.4733 124.127 9.08667 124.48 7.46 124.48C6.38 124.48 5.31333 124.28 4.26 123.88C4.23333 124.147 4.20667 124.38 4.18 124.58ZM5.7 110.08C5.51333 110.08 5.32 110.08 5.12 110.08C4.98667 112.56 4.86667 114.673 4.76 116.42C4.65333 118.153 4.56 119.6 4.48 120.76C4.88 120.893 5.32 121.013 5.8 121.12C6.29333 121.213 6.80667 121.26 7.34 121.26C8.42 121.26 9.28667 120.987 9.94 120.44C10.6067 119.893 11.0867 119.173 11.38 118.28C11.6733 117.373 11.82 116.393 11.82 115.34C11.82 114.5 11.6933 113.787 11.44 113.2C11.1867 112.613 10.8533 112.127 10.44 111.74C10.04 111.353 9.6 111.053 9.12 110.84C8.64 110.613 8.16667 110.447 7.7 110.34C7.24667 110.233 6.84 110.167 6.48 110.14C6.12 110.1 5.86 110.08 5.7 110.08ZM22.8375 124.64C21.7708 124.64 20.8375 124.467 20.0375 124.12C19.2508 123.773 18.5975 123.3 18.0775 122.7C17.5575 122.087 17.1708 121.387 16.9175 120.6C16.6642 119.813 16.5375 118.987 16.5375 118.12C16.5375 117.24 16.6908 116.427 16.9975 115.68C17.3175 114.92 17.7508 114.26 18.2975 113.7C18.8575 113.14 19.5108 112.707 20.2575 112.4C21.0042 112.08 21.8175 111.92 22.6975 111.92C23.6175 111.92 24.4708 112.08 25.2575 112.4C26.0442 112.72 26.7308 113.167 27.3175 113.74C27.9042 114.313 28.3575 114.987 28.6775 115.76C29.0108 116.533 29.1775 117.373 29.1775 118.28C29.1775 120.293 28.6242 121.86 27.5175 122.98C26.4108 124.087 24.8508 124.64 22.8375 124.64ZM22.8175 121.4C23.7908 121.4 24.5308 121.127 25.0375 120.58C25.5575 120.033 25.8175 119.247 25.8175 118.22C25.8175 117.3 25.5375 116.56 24.9775 116C24.4175 115.44 23.6842 115.16 22.7775 115.16C22.2308 115.16 21.7308 115.307 21.2775 115.6C20.8242 115.88 20.4575 116.26 20.1775 116.74C19.9108 117.207 19.7775 117.727 19.7775 118.3C19.7775 118.807 19.8775 119.3 20.0775 119.78C20.2908 120.26 20.6242 120.653 21.0775 120.96C21.5308 121.253 22.1108 121.4 22.8175 121.4ZM35.7652 124.58C34.7652 124.58 33.8585 124.32 33.0452 123.8C32.2318 123.293 31.5852 122.607 31.1052 121.74C30.6385 120.86 30.4052 119.88 30.4052 118.8C30.4052 117.787 30.5918 116.873 30.9652 116.06C31.3385 115.233 31.8452 114.527 32.4852 113.94C33.1385 113.353 33.8785 112.907 34.7052 112.6C35.5318 112.28 36.3985 112.12 37.3052 112.12C38.0652 112.12 38.8118 112.227 39.5452 112.44C39.5985 112.16 39.6452 111.88 39.6852 111.6L43.1052 112.18C43.0118 112.433 42.9185 112.813 42.8252 113.32C42.7318 113.827 42.6518 114.393 42.5852 115.02C42.5318 115.647 42.4852 116.273 42.4452 116.9C42.4052 117.527 42.3852 118.093 42.3852 118.6C42.3852 119.013 42.4118 119.42 42.4652 119.82C42.5318 120.207 42.6652 120.527 42.8652 120.78C43.0652 121.02 43.3718 121.14 43.7852 121.14H44.0652L43.5652 124.62C42.6852 124.62 41.9585 124.467 41.3852 124.16C40.8118 123.867 40.3518 123.467 40.0052 122.96C39.4318 123.6 38.7785 124.027 38.0452 124.24C37.3118 124.467 36.5518 124.58 35.7652 124.58ZM33.6852 119.2C33.7518 119.84 34.0118 120.353 34.4652 120.74C34.9318 121.113 35.5185 121.3 36.2252 121.3C36.9052 121.3 37.4718 121.12 37.9252 120.76C38.3785 120.387 38.7518 119.88 39.0452 119.24C39.0318 119.027 39.0252 118.807 39.0252 118.58C39.0252 118.113 39.0385 117.633 39.0652 117.14C39.0918 116.647 39.1252 116.16 39.1652 115.68C38.6052 115.467 38.0185 115.36 37.4052 115.36C36.6852 115.36 36.0385 115.507 35.4652 115.8C34.9052 116.08 34.4652 116.473 34.1452 116.98C33.8252 117.487 33.6652 118.073 33.6652 118.74C33.6652 118.82 33.6652 118.9 33.6652 118.98C33.6652 119.06 33.6718 119.133 33.6852 119.2ZM64.5258 124.78C64.1924 124.567 63.6991 124.253 63.0458 123.84C62.4058 123.427 61.6791 122.933 60.8658 122.36C60.1991 123.053 59.3991 123.593 58.4658 123.98C57.5324 124.38 56.4191 124.58 55.1258 124.58C53.3524 124.58 51.9591 124.173 50.9458 123.36C49.9324 122.547 49.4258 121.427 49.4258 120C49.4258 119.813 49.4458 119.54 49.4858 119.18C49.5258 118.82 49.6458 118.407 49.8458 117.94C50.0458 117.473 50.3724 116.987 50.8258 116.48C51.2924 115.973 51.9391 115.48 52.7658 115L52.8458 114.96C52.4724 114.4 52.1791 113.847 51.9658 113.3C51.7524 112.753 51.6458 112.22 51.6458 111.7C51.6458 110.74 51.8258 109.94 52.1858 109.3C52.5591 108.66 53.0391 108.153 53.6258 107.78C54.2124 107.407 54.8458 107.14 55.5258 106.98C56.2191 106.82 56.8791 106.74 57.5058 106.74C58.0791 106.74 58.6658 106.807 59.2658 106.94C59.8658 107.073 60.4191 107.287 60.9258 107.58C61.4324 107.86 61.8391 108.24 62.1458 108.72C62.4524 109.187 62.6058 109.76 62.6058 110.44C62.6058 111.187 62.4658 111.84 62.1858 112.4C61.9058 112.947 61.4724 113.453 60.8858 113.92C60.2991 114.387 59.5458 114.88 58.6258 115.4C58.4124 115.52 58.1791 115.64 57.9258 115.76C58.2458 116.067 58.5991 116.387 58.9858 116.72C59.3724 117.04 59.7658 117.367 60.1658 117.7C60.3791 117.233 60.5658 116.713 60.7258 116.14C60.8858 115.553 61.0258 114.92 61.1458 114.24L64.2458 114.78C64.0458 115.66 63.8191 116.513 63.5658 117.34C63.3258 118.167 63.0324 118.94 62.6858 119.66C63.4191 120.193 64.1058 120.68 64.7458 121.12C65.3991 121.547 65.9324 121.867 66.3458 122.08L64.5258 124.78ZM54.8258 111.38C54.8258 111.807 54.9058 112.193 55.0658 112.54C55.2391 112.887 55.4458 113.207 55.6858 113.5C56.3791 113.153 56.9991 112.827 57.5458 112.52C58.0924 112.213 58.5258 111.893 58.8458 111.56C59.1658 111.227 59.3258 110.853 59.3258 110.44C59.3258 109.96 58.7258 109.72 57.5258 109.72C57.3658 109.72 57.1391 109.74 56.8458 109.78C56.5524 109.82 56.2524 109.9 55.9458 110.02C55.6391 110.127 55.3724 110.293 55.1458 110.52C54.9324 110.733 54.8258 111.02 54.8258 111.38ZM52.4658 119.86C52.4658 120.473 52.6724 120.92 53.0858 121.2C53.5124 121.48 54.2191 121.62 55.2058 121.62C55.7124 121.62 56.2258 121.527 56.7458 121.34C57.2791 121.153 57.7924 120.847 58.2858 120.42C57.6724 119.94 57.0591 119.433 56.4458 118.9C55.8458 118.367 55.2858 117.827 54.7658 117.28C54.0991 117.613 53.5458 117.987 53.1058 118.4C52.6791 118.813 52.4658 119.3 52.4658 119.86ZM74.8441 124.58L71.4841 124.28L72.2241 110.54C71.8774 110.62 71.5574 110.713 71.2641 110.82L70.6641 107.42C71.3707 107.273 72.2441 107.12 73.2841 106.96C74.3241 106.8 75.3974 106.72 76.5041 106.72C77.3574 106.72 78.2241 106.813 79.1041 107C79.9841 107.173 80.8241 107.467 81.6241 107.88C82.4374 108.28 83.1574 108.82 83.7841 109.5C84.4241 110.18 84.9241 111.013 85.2841 112C85.6574 112.987 85.8441 114.153 85.8441 115.5C85.8441 117.393 85.5374 119.013 84.9241 120.36C84.3241 121.693 83.4441 122.713 82.2841 123.42C81.1374 124.127 79.7507 124.48 78.1241 124.48C77.0441 124.48 75.9774 124.28 74.9241 123.88C74.8974 124.147 74.8707 124.38 74.8441 124.58ZM76.3641 110.08C76.1774 110.08 75.9841 110.08 75.7841 110.08C75.6507 112.56 75.5307 114.673 75.4241 116.42C75.3174 118.153 75.2241 119.6 75.1441 120.76C75.5441 120.893 75.9841 121.013 76.4641 121.12C76.9574 121.213 77.4707 121.26 78.0041 121.26C79.0841 121.26 79.9507 120.987 80.6041 120.44C81.2707 119.893 81.7507 119.173 82.0441 118.28C82.3374 117.373 82.4841 116.393 82.4841 115.34C82.4841 114.5 82.3574 113.787 82.1041 113.2C81.8507 112.613 81.5174 112.127 81.1041 111.74C80.7041 111.353 80.2641 111.053 79.7841 110.84C79.3041 110.613 78.8307 110.447 78.3641 110.34C77.9107 110.233 77.5041 110.167 77.1441 110.14C76.7841 110.1 76.5241 110.08 76.3641 110.08ZM88.0216 124.58L87.5216 121.96C87.6949 121.893 87.9016 121.833 88.1416 121.78C88.5549 121.513 89.0282 121.16 89.5616 120.72C90.1082 120.267 90.6682 119.773 91.2416 119.24C91.8149 118.707 92.3682 118.18 92.9016 117.66C93.4349 117.127 93.9016 116.647 94.3016 116.22C94.7016 115.793 94.9949 115.46 95.1816 115.22C95.2482 115.127 95.2949 115.06 95.3216 115.02C95.3482 114.967 95.3616 114.933 95.3616 114.92C95.3616 114.933 95.2682 114.94 95.0816 114.94C94.8949 114.94 94.7282 114.94 94.5816 114.94C94.1016 114.94 93.5149 114.98 92.8216 115.06C92.1416 115.127 91.4082 115.233 90.6216 115.38C89.8349 115.527 89.0482 115.727 88.2616 115.98L87.6616 112.76C89.0349 112.493 90.3416 112.293 91.5816 112.16C92.8349 112.013 94.0149 111.94 95.1216 111.94C95.5482 111.94 96.0016 111.953 96.4816 111.98C96.9749 112.007 97.4416 112.087 97.8816 112.22C98.3216 112.34 98.6816 112.547 98.9616 112.84C99.2416 113.12 99.3816 113.513 99.3816 114.02C99.3816 114.38 99.2282 114.827 98.9216 115.36C98.6282 115.88 98.2082 116.46 97.6616 117.1C97.1282 117.727 96.5016 118.387 95.7816 119.08C95.0749 119.773 94.3082 120.467 93.4816 121.16C94.2149 121.12 94.9416 121.1 95.6616 121.1C96.6882 121.1 97.5949 121.12 98.3816 121.16C99.1682 121.2 99.6882 121.253 99.9416 121.32L99.9616 124.44C99.5882 124.413 98.9882 124.387 98.1616 124.36C97.3349 124.347 96.4216 124.34 95.4216 124.34C94.4882 124.34 93.5349 124.347 92.5616 124.36C91.6016 124.387 90.7149 124.413 89.9016 124.44C89.1016 124.48 88.4749 124.527 88.0216 124.58ZM101.779 110.08C101.779 109.96 101.772 109.84 101.759 109.72C101.759 109.587 101.759 109.44 101.759 109.28C101.759 108.853 101.772 108.4 101.799 107.92C101.826 107.44 101.852 107.033 101.879 106.7L105.439 106.76C105.399 107.213 105.352 107.727 105.299 108.3C105.259 108.873 105.232 109.467 105.219 110.08H101.779ZM101.699 124.4C101.659 123.573 101.632 122.693 101.619 121.76C101.606 120.813 101.599 119.867 101.599 118.92C101.599 117.68 101.612 116.473 101.639 115.3C101.666 114.127 101.699 113.06 101.739 112.1L105.179 112.08C105.126 112.693 105.092 113.453 105.079 114.36C105.066 115.253 105.059 116.193 105.059 117.18C105.059 118.153 105.066 119.113 105.079 120.06C105.092 121.007 105.106 121.867 105.119 122.64C105.146 123.4 105.166 123.987 105.179 124.4H101.699ZM107.252 124.46C107.199 123.82 107.152 123 107.112 122C107.086 121 107.072 119.913 107.072 118.74C107.072 117.7 107.079 116.627 107.092 115.52C107.119 114.413 107.152 113.327 107.192 112.26C107.246 111.18 107.299 110.173 107.352 109.24C107.419 108.293 107.492 107.467 107.572 106.76L111.052 107C110.866 108.36 110.719 109.74 110.612 111.14C110.519 112.527 110.459 113.94 110.432 115.38C111.179 114.86 112.046 114.313 113.032 113.74C114.032 113.153 115.232 112.493 116.632 111.76L118.512 114.9C117.072 115.353 115.799 115.873 114.692 116.46C113.586 117.033 112.679 117.613 111.972 118.2C111.839 118.293 111.752 118.36 111.712 118.4C111.672 118.44 111.652 118.467 111.652 118.48C111.652 118.56 111.872 118.707 112.312 118.92C112.899 119.227 113.506 119.527 114.132 119.82C114.759 120.113 115.459 120.413 116.232 120.72C117.006 121.013 117.892 121.327 118.892 121.66L117.512 124.62C116.299 124.26 115.086 123.807 113.872 123.26C112.659 122.713 111.559 122.16 110.572 121.6C110.586 122.053 110.606 122.513 110.632 122.98C110.672 123.447 110.706 123.913 110.732 124.38L107.252 124.46ZM119.67 110.08C119.67 109.96 119.663 109.84 119.65 109.72C119.65 109.587 119.65 109.44 119.65 109.28C119.65 108.853 119.663 108.4 119.69 107.92C119.716 107.44 119.743 107.033 119.77 106.7L123.33 106.76C123.29 107.213 123.243 107.727 123.19 108.3C123.15 108.873 123.123 109.467 123.11 110.08H119.67ZM119.59 124.4C119.55 123.573 119.523 122.693 119.51 121.76C119.496 120.813 119.49 119.867 119.49 118.92C119.49 117.68 119.503 116.473 119.53 115.3C119.556 114.127 119.59 113.06 119.63 112.1L123.07 112.08C123.016 112.693 122.983 113.453 122.97 114.36C122.956 115.253 122.95 116.193 122.95 117.18C122.95 118.153 122.956 119.113 122.97 120.06C122.983 121.007 122.996 121.867 123.01 122.64C123.036 123.4 123.056 123.987 123.07 124.4H119.59ZM124.923 124.56C124.976 123.453 125.016 122.347 125.043 121.24C125.07 120.133 125.083 119.04 125.083 117.96C125.07 116.973 125.05 116 125.023 115.04C125.01 114.067 124.976 113.127 124.923 112.22L128.283 112.12C128.296 112.613 128.316 113.12 128.343 113.64C128.77 113.107 129.263 112.68 129.823 112.36C130.396 112.027 131.05 111.86 131.783 111.86C132.063 111.86 132.423 111.9 132.863 111.98C133.303 112.06 133.75 112.213 134.203 112.44L133.823 115.82C133.49 115.62 133.13 115.48 132.743 115.4C132.37 115.307 132.056 115.26 131.803 115.26C130.95 115.26 130.223 115.647 129.623 116.42C129.036 117.18 128.636 118.24 128.423 119.6C128.423 120.533 128.41 121.427 128.383 122.28C128.37 123.12 128.336 123.88 128.283 124.56H124.923Z" />
</vector>
```

Comment: Starting from Android 12 splash screens are strictly standardized, the images are cropped and shaped according to the same rules. In your screenshot, the image appears rounded. You can find more information [here](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen#elements)